# Visual Studio 2022 Code Coverage Analysis Unusual Behavior

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I am using NUnit, NSubstitute, and Visual Studio 2022 for testing an ASP.NET Core 6 Service. I'm seeing some results that I don't understand. Here is a screen capture, showing the code and the coverage results:

[image]

The color coding is saying that line 71 (throwing the new exception) is covered, but the if on line 69 is only partially covered. How is this possible? To get to line 71, both of the conditions on either side of the && operator must be executed.

Comment: I can't speak to why it's saying it's not covered, but you don't have to test `HasValue` before testing `Value`... `if (customer.Dead == 1)` is sufficient. If `customer.Dead` doesn't have a value, the comparison will evaluate to false, not throw an exception. It's easier to read and the intent is the same.

Comment: Perhaps you need to report this problem : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

The issue was that I didn't have a test case where customer.Dead.HasValue == false, or said another way, where customer.Dead == null. The database and entity allow for a null value here, but there was no unit test of null.

Comment: Please consider [accepting your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).